# BBCode, preg_replace, and named capturing groups

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

What I thought was going to be an easy implementation of two lines of code and a function, turned out to be made of fail.

On my webpage, I want to be able to type `[text]1[/text]`, and what it will do is pull the title of that ID.

```
function textFormat($text) {
    $raw = array(
        '\'\[text\](?P&lt;id&gt;.*?)\[/text\]\'is'
    );

    $out = array (
        '&lt;a href="index.php?function=getData&reference=text&id=$1"&gt;' . getTextTitle() . '&lt;/a&gt;'
    );

    preg_replace($raw, $out, $text);
    return $text;
}

function getTextTitle($id) {
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM text WHERE id = $id");
     return mysql_result($sql);
}
```

So, here's the lovely little problem: As one can tell, I'm calling a function with a numeric-titled variable, which works great in the quotation marks, but as we know, PHP doesn't like that. So, I opted for a named group. Using `$regs['id']` fails to work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: It is meant to return a tags as HTML would allow, but using the PRE's a little funky on this; sorry for any confusion this might cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're certainly doing it in a radically different way than I ever would, but I think something not too far off from what you're attempting may possibly work.  Try this:

```
function textFormat($text) {
    $raw = array(
        '\'\[text\](?P&lt;id&gt;.*?)\[/text\]\'ise'
    );
    $out = array (
        '\'&lt;a href="index.php?function=getData&reference=text&id=$1"&gt;\' . getTextTitle(\'$1\') . \'&lt;/a&gt;\''
    );
    preg_replace($raw, $out, $text);
    return $text;
}

function getTextTitle($id) {
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM text WHERE id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "'");
     $res = mysql_result($sql);
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
     return $row ? $row[0] : 'invalid ID';
}
```

Your original `getTextTitle()` would, unless something else is going on I'm not aware of, let anyone do anything they liked to your database via SQL injection, by the way.  You're welcome.

Also, I don't know what that `(?P&lt;id&gt;` noise is about in the regex, so I'm assuming it's needed for some reason and leaving it alone.  I do not know whether this is correct.

Comment: The (?P&lt;id&gt; was meant to be a named group, so that'd it return as $regs['id'], this doesn't work apparently; as for the security issue, I appreciate it--I've already put in a system of fixing that (by ensuring that only Administrators can use [text]$num[/text]. Another way would have to been for the capturing group to be (\d+?) instead of (.*?). You made mention that this isn't how you'd approach it--I'm curious, how would you?

Comment: In addition, thank you; this code is now working, though I had to scrap <code>$res = mysql_result($sql); $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);</code> All this did was generate a profuse amount of errors. I tinkered with it, changing <code>return $row</code> to say $res, but in that instance, it'd just return "invalid ID".